# Deleting query item with OOP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am having issue make this code work:

```
index.php:

    <?php 

include("config.php");

$asd=123;

$db = new db();
$db->connect();


$db->sql('SELECT id,name FROM CRUDClass');
$res = $db->getResult();

foreach($res as $output){
    echo '<div>'.$output['name'].' - <a href="" onclick="'.$db->delete('CRUDClass','id='.$output['id']).'">Delete ID: '.$output['id'].'</a></div><br>';
}

?>

config.php

<?php

    class db{

    private $result = array();
    private $myQuery = "";
    private $numResults = "";
....

public function sql($sql){

        $query = @mysql_query($sql);
        $this->myQuery = $sql; // Pass back the SQL

        if($query){

            // If the query returns >= 1 assign the number of rows to numResults
            $this->numResults = mysql_num_rows($query);

            // Loop through the query results by the number of rows returned
            for($i = 0; $i < $this->numResults; $i++){

                $r = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                $key = array_keys($r);

                for($x = 0; $x < count($key); $x++){

                    // Sanitizes keys so only alpha-values are allowed
                    if(!is_int($key[$x])){

                        if(mysql_num_rows($query) >= 1){

                            $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];

                        }else{

                            $this->result = null;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return true; // Query was successful

        }else{

            array_push($this->result,mysql_error());
            return false; // No rows where returned

        }
    }

    // Function to SELECT from the database
    public function select($table, $rows = '*', $join = null, $where = null, $order = null, $limit = null){

        // Create query from the variables passed to the function
        $q = 'SELECT '.$rows.' FROM '.$table;

        if($join != null){
            $q .= ' JOIN '.$join;
        }

        if($where != null){
            $q .= ' WHERE '.$where;
        }

        if($order != null){
            $q .= ' ORDER BY '.$order;
        }

        if($limit != null){
            $q .= ' LIMIT '.$limit;
        }

        $this->myQuery = $q; // Pass back the SQL
        // Check to see if the table exists

        if($this->tableExists($table)){
            // The table exists, run the query
            $query = @mysql_query($q);

            if($query){
                // If the query returns >= 1 assign the number of rows to numResults
                $this->numResults = mysql_num_rows($query);

                // Loop through the query results by the number of rows returned
                for($i = 0; $i < $this->numResults; $i++){

                    $r = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                    $key = array_keys($r);

                    for($x = 0; $x < count($key); $x++){

                        // Sanitizes keys so only alphavalues are allowed
                        if(!is_int($key[$x])){

                            if(mysql_num_rows($query) >= 1){

                                $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];

                            }else{

                                $this->result = null;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return true; // Query was successful

            }else{

                array_push($this->result,mysql_error());
                return false; // No rows where returned

            }

        }else{

            return false; // Table does not exist

        }
    }

    // Function to insert into the database
    public function insert($table,$params=array()){

        // Check to see if the table exists
         if($this->tableExists($table)){

            $sql='INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` (`'.implode('`, `',array_keys($params)).'`) VALUES ("' . implode('", "', $params) . '")';
            $this->myQuery = $sql; // Pass back the SQL

            // Make the query to insert to the database
            if($ins = @mysql_query($sql)){

                array_push($this->result,mysql_insert_id());
                return true; // The data has been inserted

            }else{

                array_push($this->result,mysql_error());
                return false; // The data has not been inserted

            }

        }else{

            return false; // Table does not exist

        }
    }

    //Function to delete table or row(s) from database
    public function delete($table,$where = null){

        // Check to see if table exists
         if($this->tableExists($table)){

            // The table exists check to see if we are deleting rows or table
            if($where == null){

                $delete = 'DELETE '.$table; // Create query to delete table

            }else{

                $delete = 'DELETE FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$where; // Create query to delete rows

            }

            // Submit query to database
            if($del = @mysql_query($delete)){

                array_push($this->result,mysql_affected_rows());
                $this->myQuery = $delete; // Pass back the SQL
                return true; // The query exectued correctly

            }else{

                array_push($this->result,mysql_error());
                return false; // The query did not execute correctly

            }

        }else{

            return false; // The table does not exist

        }
    }

....

    public function getResult(){
        $val = $this->result;
        $this->result = array();
        return $val;
    }

    //Pass the SQL back for debugging
    public function getSql(){
        $val = $this->myQuery;
        $this->myQuery = array();
        return $val;
    }

    //Pass the number of rows back
    public function numRows(){
        $val = $this->numResults;
        $this->numResults = array();
        return $val;
    }
}

?>
```

The problem is that when I try to delete an item in the list, it deletes all the items in my database. I can use the $get['id'] method in the link to delete the item correctly in a separate file, but I don't understand why this current code is screwing things up in the foreach?

Comment: Here is my wall of code which I didn't feel like isolating to only the problem code. What is the problem?

Comment: This code contains quite a lot of bad practices. Apart from using the [deprecated `mysql` library](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), you also suppress error messages and have poor error handling. But most importantly, you use weak comparison operators. A comparison like `$where == null` should never exist. Use `$where === null` or `is_null($where)`. By eliminating these bad practises, you will likely solve your problem, or at least be able to isolate it.

Answer (score 0):

In this:

```
 echo '<div>'.$output['name'].' - <a href="" onclick="'.$db->delete('CRUDClass','id='.$output['id']).'">Delete ID: '.$output['id'].'</a></div><br>';
```

You are expecting the delete method to be called when onclick event is fired, but this won't happen.

Currently, the delete method will be called when index.php is visited.

To make it work, change the `<a>` tag to link to a different php file and place the call to the delete method in there, or you could use the same php file in the link with a ?query in the link.

Answer (score 0):

What the hell, you're completely misunderstanding PHP xD

Let's say your code `insert, delete,...` works how you want it, than this:

```
foreach($res as $output){
    echo '<div>'.$output['name'].' - <a href="" onclick="'.$db->delete('CRUDClass','id='.$output['id']).'">Delete ID: '.$output['id'].'</a></div><br>';
}
```

... produces some `<div>Name <a href="" onclick="'true'">Delete ID: 1</a></div><br>` code. After it is created, every `delete` has been called, thus your table is empty.

PHP only produces output on the server and sends it back to the client. You have to write code like this:

```
foreach(...) {
?>
   <div><a href="delete.php?id=<?=$output['id']?>">delete me</a></div>
<?php
}
```

Then in the `delete.php` you take `$_GET['id']` and call the `delete`.

All in all it's never too early to read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. That means you have to escape the `id` parameter before inserting them into a query. I recommend to use prepared statements.

But at first, learn what PHP does :). You cannot implement PHP callbacks into HTML or what you've tried.